# angular js - how can click with the mouse followed by pressing Enter on ng-grid

Tags: javascript, angularjs, click, ng-grid, enter

I am trying to use ng-grid in angular. How can I select a row of ng-grid ,on click with the mouse followed by pressing Enter?

When click enter it changes the selected row, I don't want that.
I want return selected row on enter click.

Comment: please also show your code.

Comment: Update your question to describe what is "enter click" (don't use a comment), is it a click with the mouse followed by pressing Enter on the keyboard. Is it clicking Enter on a page. And what about "click enter" is that the same, or something different?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, looking at the API docs which are here:

http://angular-ui.github.io/ng-grid/

Under: API documentation

You want the option

```
enableCellEdit  false
```

Globally allows all cells to be editable. use the editableCellTemplate option to override the default text input    Link

To be off, since you mentioned editing is not what you want, and finally you want to capture the clicked cell information which is done with

```
beforeSelectionChange   function (rowItem, event) { return true; }
```

Function in the ng-grid options to call one of your functions, giving you the rowItem information you are interested in.